# Problems with turning a timedelta calculation into " %A, %B %d, %Y"

Tags: python, timedelta

I want to use the following code snippet to turn a generator of upcoming days into readable words, that I will store in a list, using .strftime(" %A, %B %d, %Y").

```
base = datetime.today()
date_list = [base - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 7)]
datescroll_list = ()
```

However, what gets returned is in an unreadable format. The methods I know of turning that format into a readable format is not working.

Comment: Show the code that isn't working

Comment: For upcoming days wouldn't you want `base + timedelta(days=x)`?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and fixed it. thanks for pointing it out tho..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code works fine if you add parens then call strftime:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
base = datetime.today()
date_list = [(base - timedelta(days=x)).strftime(" %A, %B %d, %Y") for x in range(0, 7)]
print(date_list)
```

Output:

```
[' Saturday, June 20, 2015', ' Friday, June 19, 2015', ' Thursday, June 18, 2015', ' Wednesday, June 17, 2015', ' Tuesday, June 16, 2015', ' Monday, June 15, 2015', ' Sunday, June 14, 2015']
```

Comment: No prob, adding the parens means the `base - timedelta(days=x)` is evaluated first then we call strftime on the returned datetime object.